# Getting number of rows having specific .data() value

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a table, with few rows having class `SomeClass`.
For few of those rows (having the class), I'm storing `.data("MyKey")` with different value for each row.
I need the number of rows with class as `SomeClass` and `.data("MyKey")` as `MyValue`.

I tried something like this:

```
$("#tbl tr.SomeClass").data('MyKey') == "MyValue" //.length
```

But I know this is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter` method:

```
var count = $('#tbl tr.SomeClass').filter(function(){
      return $(this).data('MyKey') === 'MyValue';
}).length;
```

Or `Attribute Equals` selector:

```
$("#tbl tr.SomeClass").filter('[data-MyKey="MyValue"]').length;
```